# Appending a list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm just starting logic programming(in Prolog), and it's very different from procedure/OO. Please help out:

```
male(a).
male(b).
male(c).

female(x).
female(y).

append([],X,X).
append([X|Y],Z,[X|W]):- append(Y,Z,W).

partners(X,Y):- male(X), female(Y).
```

I'm trying to write a predicate getAllPartners(MyList, Output) that outputs a list including all possible combinations of partners. I don't mind having 0s in the list, but if anyone figure out a way of not having 0s in the output list, that'll be awesome.
Here's my 'buggy, crappy' code, please help:

```
getAllPartners(MyList, Output):-
append([],0,MyList),
partners(X,Y),
append(MyList,X,Output),
append(Output,Y,MyList),
append(MyList,0,Output).
```

Comment: Why would there be zero's in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of manually appending such lists, Prolog has a builtin `findall`:

```
getAllPartners(L) :-
  findall((M,F),(male(M),female(F)),L).
```

Or even more compact:

```
getAllPartners(L) :-
  findall((M,F),partners(M,F),L).
```

When you call:

```
getAllPartners(L).
```

It will respond with:

```
L = [ (a, x), (a, y), (b, x), (b, y), (c, x), (c, y)].
```

---

You can generate your list manually, as well, but the problem with your approach is that `partners(X,Y)` will always bind with the same people first. Your list is thus `[ a, x, 0, a, x, 0, a, x, 0, ...]`. Another problem you should resolve is the fact that you append "lists" and not a "list" with an "element".

Comment: I see. But I am also interested in learning how to implement findall as well! Is there some good tutorial for doing the 'findall' trick??

Comment: @Tuan333: Implementing the `findall`  yourself, or learn how to invoke the predicate properly?

Comment: Yes, I would appreciate it if you could direct me to a tutorial to implement findall or something similar to that so that if I don't know the proper function, I could still implement it. I'm struggling to get used to this programming paradigm.

Comment: Source code is available here (there are several implementations) http://ai.ia.agh.edu.pl/wiki/pl:prolog:pllib:findall, but it requires low level predicates that are in most cases advanced. My PhD advisor rewrote the source code later.